# Django contect_object_name is not producing a context dict in view

Tags: python, django

I am back with more django questions on CBVs.  This is about `context_object_name`.  I have the following:

```
@method_decorator(verified_email_required, name='dispatch')
class Create(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    context_object_name = 'profileForm'
    template_name = 'Members/template_includes/profile/form.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = '/Members'
    form_title = "New Login Profile Information"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            return render(request, self.template_name, {
                'profileTitle': self.form_title,
            })
```

I am using PyCharm and can put a breakpoint in the `template_name` form and see what the environment knows about.  I expect to see a dict named `profileForm` with all the form members in it plus `profileTitle`.  Instead I see `profileTitle` as a standalone member.  I do not see anything named `profileForm` or `object_list` and the expected form members are not being painted in the template.

I suppose that I understand that the extra content in the `return render` will pass a "naked" `profileTitle` but I did expect that the default `get` behaviour would pull in the form info.

Have I missed the point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've overridden the `get` method in your `CreateView`-subclass and in doing so, you've bypassed the included functionality that a `CreateView` does to fill your context. If you take a look [here](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get) you can see that a `CreateView` would otherwise call `return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())` (because it inherits from ProcessFormView) and it's within `get_context_data()` ([ref](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_context_data)) that those included context variables are set up.